# How does one compare different versions of MSMDPump.dll?

Tags: webforms, ssas, sql-server-2016, olap, olap-cube

I am trying to implement MSMDPump.dll on my web server to allow my users to connect to several cubes I have on a SSAS server. I was reading this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=asallproducts-allversions)  and it says I need to pull that file from (**< drive >:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\\OLAP\bin\isapi**), however on different servers I have different versions of this file (with different versions of SQL).

I would like to determine the differences between these files, however, when searching the web, I have not been able to find any release documentation. Does anyone know whether this information is posted publicly somewhere? If not, how would one determine the best version to use in their specific environment as well as the effects of using each version on my cube connection and the users of my application?